# CSS card overlay with image and text

Tags: html, css, hover, overlay

I am trying to create an overlay that will cover an entire div/card. I have three cards that I want to rollover black when active. For some reason, I can't get the entire div to be selected.

HTML:

```
  <div class="item "> 
  <div class="overlay">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/600x350">
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <p> Text</p>
  </div><div class="overlay"> </div> 
  </div>
```

and CSS:

```
 .item {

    padding: 0px 0;
  margin: 1%;
    border-radius: 2px;
  flex: 1 250px;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #efefef, #ffffff);
}

.overlay {
  position: relative;
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0)
   -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
   transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}


.overlay:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);

}
```

[CODEPEN EXAMPLE](http://codepen.io/sethrr/pen/oBvWwb)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`div.item` has a certain size and shape. Style it as `relative` so that the next thing will work

Make `div.overlay` `position:absolute` - that will overlay it, but it has no size, so it will still be invisible.

Then, make `div.overlay` the full height of its parent (`div.item`).

When made visible (at :hover) it will be 100% height/width of .item, and will overlay it.

```css
body {background-color: #C70025;}

img {width: 100%;}

#container {width:90%;margin:0 auto;display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap;
justify-content:space-between;}

.item {color:#000;padding:0px 0;margin:1%;border-radius:2px;flex:1 250px;height:auto;text-align:center;background:linear-gradient(0deg, #efefef, #ffffff);}

.item{position:relative;}
.overlay {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
   -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
   transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
.overlay:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);

}
```

```html
<div id="container">
   <div class="item "> 
      <img src="http://placehold.it/600x350">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p> Text</p>
      <div class="overlay"> </div> 
   </div>
   <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/600x350">
      <h2> Title </h2>
      <p>Text</p>
      <div class="overlay"> </div> 
   </div>
   <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/600x350">
      <h2> Title </h2>
      <p>Text</p>
      <div class="overlay"> </div> 
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, this is most likely what the OP wanted to achieve. I deleted my answer.

Comment: Kind of you to say Fred. Usually you nail it, so nice that this time I got lucky. : )

Comment: @Fred-ii- OOh, just saw your profile link to Dylan Moran. Grew up in Mtl - fav city, and Black Books is a *classic* Great link - thanks and Happy New Year!

Comment: Yeah, I didn't quite grasp what they wanted to do, you're nailed it ;-) Yeah Dylan is one of my favorite comedians, liked him from the first time I saw him. Saw George Carlin live once too; great show. I guess you can tell why I can be a bit of a joker ;-) Cheers and Happy New Year to you also :-)